# DNA Longevity in Keratin, Ivory and other Bioplastics

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, forensics

For how long is DNA viable for extraction and/or sequencing in bioplastics created by the human body? I checked out a few links online, and [this article](http://mentalfloss.com/article/48815/how-long-does-dna-last) gives a record of about 7000 years for frozen mitochondrial DNA, and [Ötzi's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96tzi) DNA remined viable for [5000 years](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms1701). However, I suspect that the samples used to analyze both were not taken from anything that was like keratin or ivory, with their limited cellular matrix. What is the longest record of sequence-viable DNA being stored that way?